# Cannot install inotify on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, inotify, inotifywait, inotify-tools

I have an AWS EC2 instance and wants to install inotify-tools. I've added the repository by executing the command: rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm then execute yum install inotify-tools but getting No package inotify-tools available.

Please help

Answer (score 29):

I bumped into this issue as well. The solution below is a bit easier than grabbing an RPM or the source and compiling.

The Amazon Linux AMI comes with the EPEL repository source, but it's disabled. So you need to enable it.

Original Amazon Linux (1) AMI:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

Amazon Linux 2 AMI:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

Then run a regular `yum update` and install the toolset:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install inotify-tools
```

Comment: Thanks @Neal. Changed the approach on file synchronization accross EC2 instances so I haven't actually tried this one out. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Not working for me. 
No package inotify-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: @AkashChauhan - see updated instructions, per Sairam below. Amazon Linux 2 changed the command slightly.

Answer (score 3):

[How do I enable the EPEL repository for my Amazon EC2 instance running CentOS, RHEL, or Amazon Linux?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/)

Install and enable the EPEL rpm package on RHEL 7 and **Amazon Linux 2**

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Voted both answers up. To resolve my issue I did following 3 steps

1. sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm (answer by @mon)
2. sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
3. sudo yum update
4. sudo yum install inotify-tools
(answer by @Neal)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo yum install inotify-tools
```

For me, none of the above answers worked. I had to install `epel-release` and then install `inotify-tools`